# For loop to print variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print variables vector1 and vector2 in Python 3, without having to write the print code manually. How can I do this? Below you can see the code that I tried using for this.

```
vectorInput = input("Enter vectors values separated by ',' and vectors separated by ' ': ")

vector1,vector2 = vectorInput.split(" ")

for num in range(1,3):
    print({}.format('vector'+num))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use comprehensions directly.

```
[print(i) for i in vectorInput.split(" ")]
```

Or use `list` of vectors, as it more fits in your usage pattern, and ou can reuse it later.

```
vectors = vectorInput.split(" ")
[print(i) for i in vectors]
```

Or with `for`

```
vectors = vectorInput.split(" ")
for i in vectors:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the shorter version give a try.

```
for i in input("Enter vectors values separated by ',' and vectors separated by ' ': ").split():
    print(f'vector {i}')
```

If you want *i* as an integer then replace *i* with `int(i)`

Comment: Note: this method using [fstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) is only available for python > 3.6.

Comment: That is right. @Marcel, you can also use print('vector {0}'.format(i)).